# VB.NET How to compare string date

Tags: vb.net

I have a string of dates formatted like `September 27, 2016`. How can I compare that to today's date so that I can get the difference in days?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim diff = DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse("September 27, 2016")
MsgBox diff.Days
```